# BER for OFDM-QPSK over Rayleigh Channel

Tags: matlab, ofdm

The rayleigh channel is a single tap.

```
   1.
    h=1/sqrt(2)*randn(1,length(txSig_cp))+1i*randn(1,length(txSig_cp));
    fading=h.*txSig_cp;

   2.
    h=1/sqrt(2)*(randn(1,1)+1i*randn(1,1));
    fading=conv(h,txSig_cp);
```

Which one is correct? or both also wrong. Because I have obtained different results when compared to the berfading function in MATLAB (`berfading(EbNoVec,'psk',4,1)`).

Answer (score 2):

> w = conv(u,v) returns the convolution of vectors u and v. If u and v
> are vectors of polynomial coefficients, convolving them is equivalent
> to multiplying the two polynomials. (from MATLAB documentation)

Both expressions are correct. In 2., whenever an addend of a convolution operation calls randn in a convolution computation procedure, the callee returns new values for both real and imaginary parts of h.

Answer (score 2):

The first `h` is not [single-tap](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/146703/what-is-a-channel-tap). Also, if `txSig_cp` is time domain signal, and if you want to emulate channel, the element-wise multiplication is simply wrong.

The second `h` is single-tap and using `conv()` is correct. Nevertheless, be careful taking into account [fft/ifft normalization](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html#buuutyt-5) in calculating EbNo (assuming you are using MATLAB implementations).

Comment: I think I got it wrong there because I only use the conventional way of calculating EbNo. May I know how to do that EbNo calculation?

Comment: Also am I correct in comparing it with the result via Berfading function?

Comment: Here you are https://www.gaussianwaves.com/2008/11/relation-between-ebn0-and-snr-2/. And the simplest way to avoid error is that generating the noise in the sample domain of your signal, i.e. both in frequency domain or both in time domain.

Comment: I have never used `berfading()` but I presume that being MATLAB built-in function, it is correct.